# My program makes a new file but with the wrong name. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

```
import os.path

def start():
    if os.path.exists("new.txt") == False:
        Account = input('Username: ')
        Password_for_account = input('Password: ')
        all_the_content = []
        all_the_content.append(Account)
        all_the_content.append(Password_for_account)
        
    else:
        with open("new.txt") as file:
            content = file.read()
        all_the_content = content.strip('][').split(', ')

        while True:
            User = input('Username: ')
            Password = input('Password: ')
            if (User, Password) == all_the_content[0,1] :
                print('Done')
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid Password')
                continue
        return 'You have been succesfully logged in!'
print(start())
with open("new.txt") as file:
    content = file.read()
all_the_content = content.strip('][').split(', ')
def add_new_pass():
    new_username = input('Enter the new username: ')
    new_password = input('Enter the new password: ')
    all_the_content.append(new_username)
    all_the_content.append(new_password)
    return 'Your password has been added'
    
def check_pass(username):
    position = all_the_content.index(username)
    if username in all_the_content and position%2 == 0:
        return 'The password for '+ username, 'is '+ all_the_content[position + 1]
    else:
        return 'Invalid username'
print(add_new_pass())
a = input()
print(check_pass(a))
with open ('new.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(all_the_content))
```

I am a beginner. This code does everything as expected except one thing, every time I make thefile as "new.txt". Any help is appreciated!
it stores it as "new2.txt". I am using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Seems fine, all opens are done with `new.txt` as filename. Seems like something underlying is responsible for this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a new.txt in that folder that's why it names this one new2.txt, erase or rename the first one and try to run you program agian.

Comment: could you try using a different name like test.txt and see what happens.

Comment: Sure I'll try that.

Comment: Meaning? When you open the folder to which this program outputs, do you see test2.txt?

Comment: No I see list.txt (that's what I named it). But there are other errors

Comment: Yeah, you need to change line 20 to if (User, Password) == all_the_content[0:1] :

Comment: It pretty much works now. There is another aspect that doesn't work. You method worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the other problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

Either you are not looking in the correct directory or the directory already has an existing file by the same name. Also check your write access to the directory